# CakePHP Warnings

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I have these warnings appearing on my page when I'm in debug.  Otherwise my page is just white.

Warning (512): Cache not configured properly. Please check Cache::config(); in APP/config/core.php [CORE/cake/libs/configure.php, line 645]

Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for 'PST/-8.0/no DST' instead in /var/www/vhosts/reviewsie.com/httpdocs/cake/libs/cake_log.php on line 93

How do I fix this?

Comment: seems to be a memcache problem?

Comment: Did you check the cache configuration in core.php? What's it look like?

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment the line with `date_default_timezone_set` in `app/config/core.php` and the warnings should go away.

Comment: And if you can edit your `php.ini` file, there's a property called `date.timezone` that you can uncomment and set (which is the source of the warning).